# Netbeans 8.0 not working with LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, netbeans, gradle, libgdx

I have NetBeans 8.0, Java 8, the most recent NBAndroid and Gradle plugins, and I'm trying to open a Gradle LibGDX project. I can open it fine in Eclipse (Android Studio), but when I open it in NetBeans, it doesn't even recognize the Android source:

[image: Image of NetBeans not working]

Is there a way to get NetBeans to recognize the source of the Android subproject?

I have verified the Gradle/LibGDX build stuff. It works in Eclipse, and on my partners Eclipse. It just doesn't work on NetBeans.

Comment: Hmm ok... I'm using Android Studio now for Android...

Answer (score 1):

Installing Android SDK, setting the environment vars, then installing Gradle Support (from main plugin center) and Android Support & Android Gradle Support (from NBAndroid, http://nbandroid.org/updates/updates.xml) in NetBeans worked for me, for better or worse, YMMV. Those plugins are constantly updated; beware of occasional bugs though.

OTOH, using Android Studio in parallel with NB proved to be a real time saver for me. AS is developed lot faster than NB Android plugins, so if you're expecting some heavy-duty coding/testing, AS is the way to go IMO. Simply manage your code with NB and use AS to compile/debug/launch/package your apps (both apps have update hooks, so you literally can use them at the same time). NB has currently nowhere the amount of support for Android development that is usually required.

Comment: Yup. I'm using Android Studio fully now though, since I do a lot of android development now. Wow this was a long time ago...

I think certain bugs have been fixed recently which is why it works now...